# javascript google map setcenter and setzoom with animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map api in javascript, i need to change zoom and center by the value coming from restful service and i can do that with setCenter and setZoom functions.

But the problem is that, map is reloading and my boss want it to focus that location with an animation not by reloading map is there anyway for doing so?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The method `setCenter` reloads the map. For disabling map reloading and enabling the animation, use the `panTo` method: [Map.panTo Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/map#Map.panTo)

Comment: I want to animation speed to equal the speed reported by GPS. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 25):

According to [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map), this method:

> panTo(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)

Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

So you can simply use:

```
map.panTo(location);
```

where:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var mapOptions = {
// your map options
                };  
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); // map-canvas is id of your map holder
```