# map.setCenter(); not working when used from within StageWebView AS3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am working on an AIR Android project and I needed to give the user an option to select a location from a map. Everything else works perfectly. I am able to transfer selected lats and lngs from JS to AS. But I also want the map to center it's position to user's location when it first loads up. To do that I followed the google maps documentation and it worked perfectly in HTML. But it turns out "Geocoder" doesn't work in StageWebView. So after lots of failing I decided to use AS3's geolocation services and send Lats and Lngs from AS3 to JS when the maps loads up. To do that, in AS I find the user's position and user the following JS injection inside the WebViewLoaded event:

```
webView.loadURL("javascript:setMapCenter('" + _lats + "', '" + _lngs + "')");
```

Now here is the setMapCenter function in JS:

```
function setMapCenter(lats, lngs){

ASLats = lats;
ASLngs = lngs;
pos = {
    lat: ASLats,
    lng: ASLngs
  };
   // map.setCenter({lat:ASLats, lng:ASLngs});
    map.setCenter(pos);
    alert("set map center function was called with " + pos.lat + " " + pos.lng);
}
```

When I run AIR project, and open the map. As soon as the map loads, I get the alert window showing the lats and lngs recieved from AS3. Which means the injection is correct and the values are being successfully send from AS to JS. The problem is

```
map.setCenter({lat:ASLats, lng:ASLngs});
```

or
    map.setCenter(pos);

doesn't really work. The map doesn't center itself correctly. But when I call the same function insde the

```
window.onload(){};
```

in JS like this

```
setMapCenter(50.256498, -0.25468);
```

it works perfectly.

I really don't understand why it doesn't work. It's getting pretty frustrating. I am sorry if it sounds like a dumb question. I actually have no prior experience with JS. This is the first I am working with it. So any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling `setMapCenter('50.256498', '-0.25468');` via `loadURL`?  Your direct JS call doesn't include the quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059424/google-maps-api-for-javascript-isnt-working-properly-when-used-in-an-air-androi / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726622/javascript-google-map-setcenter-and-setzoom-with-animation